# Light 2D and Performance issues

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, 3d, 2d, lighting

I want to make a 2D game that will use 2 kinds of lights (Spotlight and Point Light). I need the game to be completly dark unless there is a light in the area and the light to not pass through walls. I tried lots of stuff and plugins to try and make this possible but nothing worked for me.

So I thought I would try to add 3D walls with an Orthographic camera so that I would have the light stop at the walls and cast shadows and make it look 2D at the same time. (Top-down View)

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to do this without needing the 3D stuff?
2. I believe that I will probably have some performance issues if I keep the 3D stuff. Is there a way to fix that since the final output from the orthographic camera is 2D? Like maybe an option to render it as 2D and not having the game process all those triangles? (I want it as light as possible because I also want to port on phones)

Comment: I'd recommend looking for [2D Light](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=2d&light&only:packages) on the asset store.

Comment: I did try the free ones ( I need it to be free for what I need) but only one worked and it actually didn't work for me as I wanted and it was very limited to change.